# Dynamic Count Function SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a dynamic count function, where I pass the table and column names as well as the column names for the criteria for count: here is what I have, but I get and error trying to create:

```
USE [testdb1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ItemCount](
@TableName [varchar](255), 
@PKIDName [varchar](255), 
@IDValue Integer, 
@ColumnName [varchar](255),
@ColumnValue [varchar](255)
)
RETURNS [varchar](100) AS 
BEGIN
      DECLARE @Result integer

      select @Result =count(*) 
      from @TableName where @PKIDName = @IDValue and @ColumnName = @ColumnValue

      RETURN @Result
END
```

Would also like if possible be able to pass the comparison operator (e.g. = in example above) such as <> or >.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use variables for table names.  You'll have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: What Dan said - the same is true for column names here as well.

Comment: I'm not sure Dynamic Sql is allowed in user defined functions. Also, you are declaring your function as `returns varchar(100)` but returning an `integer`, which is not even a valid sql server data type - it should be `int`.

Comment: But dynamic sql is not going to help here because this is a function and you can't use dynamic sql in a function. I have to ask, why do you need such a generic count function anyway? By the time you create all the parameters you only need about 20 more characters and you have the whole statement written.

Comment: @ZoharPeled integer is absolutely a valid datatype. It is an int. It is backwards compatible from when you when you had to define the name as integer. Somewhere around 6.5 if I recall correctly.

Comment: @SeanLange well that's a surprise to me. I've never seen `integer` in the documentation, only `int`. but other then that my last comment still stands.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you have to go back a bit to find it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(v=sql.80).aspx And yes everything in your comment is 100% on point!! Especially the return type.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks. This day wasn't a complete waste :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better suited for a stored procedure.  In the SET @SQLStatement you can also update the " = " to variables and update the comparison operators through the new variables.  Note @IDValue is set to varchar for the purposes of concatenation so you will have to put quotes around it (i.e. '1').  However, the string will read it is an integer when the script executes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ItemCount
(
@TableName [varchar](255), 
@PKIDName [varchar](255), 
@IDValue [varchar](255), 
@ColumnName [varchar](255),
@ColumnValue [varchar](255)
)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLStatment VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLStatment = 'SELECT COUNT(*) [RowCount] FROM ' +  @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @PKIDName + ' = ' + @IDValue + ' AND ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CHAR(39) + @ColumnValue + CHAR(39);

EXECUTE(@SQLStatment)

END
```

You can run your procedure as follows if you are not familiar with stored procedure, just insert the appropriate values.

```
EXEC dbo.ItemCount @TableName, @PKIDName, @IDValue, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue;
```